# Applying a type transformation to a list: is "const" special?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, template-meta-programming

The following applies a type transformation `F` to a list `C` of types `E...`:

```
template <template <typename...> class F, typename P> struct apply_t;

template <
    template <typename...> class F,
    template <typename...> class C, typename... E
> struct apply_t <F, C <E...> > { typedef C <F <E>...> type; };

template <template <typename...> class F, typename P>
using apply = typename apply_t<F, P>::type;
```

Now, giving this input:

```
template <typename T> using map1 = T*;
template <typename T> using map2 = const T;
template <typename T> using map3 = const T*;
```

I get the following output in gcc 4.8.1, using e.g. `std::tuple`:

```
apply <map1, tuple <int, char> >  // -> tuple <int*, char*>  (OK)

apply <map2, tuple <int, char> >  // -> tuple <int, char>
  // (tuple <const int, const char> expected)

apply <map3, tuple <int, char> >  // -> tuple <const int*, const char*> (OK)
```

I can see the output types using a utility template function that calls `static_assert()`.

I've tried all sorts of combinations. Everything works except for the map `const T` in particular, when given as an input type map to `apply`. But still works ok if I embed it in the definition of `apply`, i.e. `typedef C <const E...> type`.

On the other hand, everything works as expected in clang. I may be missing something, but it really seems like a gcc bug to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I agree that it's most likely a GCC bug; it seems to be dropping top-level const. Have you searched GCC bug reports or reported it? http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try if no other idea comes up. I the meantime the only workaround I can think of is a hard-coded `apply_const`, however ugly this may be.

Comment: Does it work with std::add_const?

Comment: No, still the same. It's now confirmed (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete but reduced testcase, you might want to add this to the GCC bug report (if you need to write one):

```
template< typename T > using Map = const T;

template< template<typename> class M, typename T >
struct Apply;

template< template<typename> class M, template<typename...> class C, typename... Ts >
struct Apply< M, C<Ts...> > { typedef C<M<Ts>...> type; };

template< typename T > struct A {};
template<typename> void dummy();

int main()
{
    dummy< Apply<Map,A<int>>::type >();    
}
```

will fail to link because of

```
undefined reference to `void dummy<A<int> >()'
```

instead of the expected

```
undefined reference to `void dummy<A<const int> >()'
```

(I know this doesn't solve the problem, but the GCC folks will likely prefer a reduced testcase without any dependency on `std::tuple` or any other header).

Comment: @iavr Thanks. I added a comment to the bug report showing a work-around and to highlight what possibly triggers this behaviour in GCC.